# System.Data.DuplicateNameException: A column named '..' already belongs to this DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, hana

How do I fix `Exception Details: System.Data.DuplicateNameException: A column named '..' already belongs to this DataTable.` error when I used join inside the sql query? It works without join (obviously)

```
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        HanaConnection conn;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        
        conn = new HanaConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Hana"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
         
        using (HanaCommand cmd = new HanaCommand("SELECT top 3* FROM A T0 LEFT OUTER JOIN B T1 ON T1.\"something\"= T0.\"somethingsecond\" ", conn))
        {
            HanaDataReader productInfoReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = productInfoReader;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        };
        conn.Close();
        
       
 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are joining two tables that both contain a column with a particular name but you're not joining on that column. This would produce a result set with two columns with identical names and that would cause that exception when a `DataTable` was generated based on that schema.

Instead of using a wildcard, you should specify the columns to include explicitly and then provide an alias for one or both of those columns. The `DataTable` will then use the alias and there will be no column name clash. As an example, instead of this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Table1Id
```

use this:

```sql
SELECT t1.Name AS T1Name, t2.Name AS T2Name, ...
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Table1Id
```